# How can I print a complex dictionary data type in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, printing

I'd like to print a result from a sparql query which gives the following dictionary data type:

```
{u'head': {u'vars': [u'synonym', u'label', u'gloss']}, u'results': {u'bindings': [{u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-05256358-n-1'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'risco'}}, {u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-08593924-n-2'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'risco'}}, {u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-08593924-n-1'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'linha'}}, {u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-08593924-n-3'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'tra\xe7o'}}, {u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-04683136-n-1'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'risco'}}, {u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-04683136-n-2'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'listra'}}, {u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-14541852-n-3'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'perigo'}}, {u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-14541852-n-2'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'amea\xe7a'}}, {u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-14541852-n-1'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'risco'}}, {u'gloss': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'um risco empreendido sem levar em conta poss\xedveis perdas ou danos'}, u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-00802238-n-2'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'risco'}}, {u'gloss': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'um risco empreendido sem levar em conta poss\xedveis perdas ou danos'}, u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-00802238-n-1'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'perigo'}}, {u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-14541044-n-2'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'amea\xe7a'}}, {u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-14541044-n-1'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'risco'}}, {u'synonym': {u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-14541044-n-3'}, u'label': {u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'perigo'}}]}}
```

I'm trying to print it, but I get this error message:

```
0 http://arademaker.github.com/wn30-br/instances/wordsense-05256358-n-1 |--| risco |--|

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/marceloschiessl/RDF_text_project/tese/testDevelop.py", line 70, in <module>

print result[var]["value"],"|--|",

KeyError: u'gloss'
```

I know I have values for the variable u'gloss' only for two records. I guess this is the problem.

I have this code to print it:

```
for i,result in enumerate(result_set["results"]["bindings"]) :
    print i, 
    for var in result_set["head"]["vars"] :
        print result[var]["value"],"|--|",
    print
```

Can anyone help me?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sk11 gave some examples where I could realize what to do! It is simpler than I was thinking, look:

```
for i,result in enumerate(result_set["results"]["bindings"]) :
    print i,
    for var in result_set["head"]["vars"] :
        if var in result:#to test whether all variables exists or not
            print result[var]["value"],": ",
    print
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can simply check whether the key is in the dictionary or not by

```
if key in dict
```

Having said that, depending upon what do want to do when key `'gloss'` is not found in the dict you can do either of following:

This prints all other keys' values except `'gloss'`:

```
for i,result in enumerate(result_set["results"]["bindings"]) :
    print i, 
    for var in result_set["head"]["vars"]:
        if var != 'gloss':
            print result[var]["value"],"|--|",
    print
```

This just prints the value for key `'gloss'`

```
for i,result in enumerate(result_set["results"]["bindings"]) :
    print i, 
    for var in result_set["head"]["vars"]:
        if 'gloss' in result: # Checks whether you have gloss key in the result dict
            print result[var]["value"],"|--|",
    print
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks @sk11! Reading your examples, I could realize what I have to do. Actually, I just want to print all keys' values, with or without 'gloss'.

Comment: So now you know how to proceed. Glad it helped !